# spork/guard reload schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spork

I use spork and guard to speed up the test suite in my Rails 3.2 application. However the tests in guard behave strange after adding a new migration: they act as they don't know about the changes in schema, even though I run `rake db:migrate` before. They start to behave correctly when I stop guard and run `rake spec`. I suppose that it behaves this way, because spork/guard doesn't update schema before tests. Is it possible to configure spork to update schema on `#prefork` and guard to reload spork on schema changes?

Comment: what database are you using for tests? try to run `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:test:clone` after migrations.

Comment: Works with `db:test:prepare`. Could you add an answer so that I can accept it ;-). I use mysql btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `rake db:test:prepare` to apply migrations for testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the following default Spork setup code should reload schema each time a test is run. Do you have it?

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
  silence_stream STDOUT do
    load Rails.root.join('db', 'schema.rb') # use db agnostic schema by default
    load Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds.rb')
  end
```

Comment: Is it a code from spork or I should add it? Btw. I don't want to reload it every time, but every time schema changes.

Comment: I think it is from spork, placed under spec_helper.rb. For me, reloading schema before each test does not take noticeable time.